# Pegar o input de form-check-label

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Olá!
Estou com uma dúvida pra pegar o input de uma form, já pesquisei por aqui e não achei nada, também não achei na documentação do JS nem do Bootstrap.

```js
var yearStu = document.querySelector(".form-check-label").value;
  alert(yearStu);
```

```html
HTML:
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1" value="1º Ano">1º Ano</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2" value="2º Ano">2º Ano</label>
      </div>
```

Essa query só esta me devolvendo "undefined". --'
Sou iniciante, se puderem me dar um auxílio.
Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

**Primeiro:** você está pegando o **`value`** da `label` e não do `input`
. **Segundo:** você está chamando o **alert** direto, assim, o value ainda não foi capturado, precisando de uma função para mostrar o alert apenas depois de o valor ter sido capturado:

```js
var yearStu = document.querySelectorAll(".form-check-input");  // referencia os inputs

yearStu.forEach((input) => {  // percorre cada input
  input.onclick = () => {
    alert(input.value)
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="1º Ano" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">1º Ano</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="2º Ano" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">2º Ano</label>
</div>
```

> Aconselharia você primeiro compreender bem o **Html** pra depois partir para o **Javascript**, sem saber o primeiro ficará mais difícil o aprendizado do segundo. Ótimo material pode ser encontrado [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML).

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Não foi nada :)